# How can I check that malicious users are not submitting a disabled ListItem from a RadioButtonList in C#?

Tags: validation, selection, radiobuttonlist

Suppose I have a `RadioButtonList` control:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbSubscriptionType" runat="server">  
      <asp:ListItem Value="Eval" Selected="True">Evaluation</asp:ListItem>  
      <asp:ListItem Value="Monthly" Enabled="false">Monthly Subscription (not available yet)</asp:ListItem>  
      <asp:ListItem Value="Yearly" Enabled="false">Yearly Subscription </asp:ListItem>  
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

A malicious user can indeed submit to the server with a **POST** action a `ListItem` with `Enabled = "false"`. I would like to forbid this behavior.

On server side I can simply check:

```
if( rdbSubscriptionType.SelectedItem.Enabled == true)
```

but I am not sure whether a malicious user can change the **enabled status** of the control also from client side, with **Javascript** or similar techniques. Is there any best practice to perform this validation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about the business rules that suround the decision to make something "disabled".

If the only check you're doing is based on what comes back from the front end, you're in trouble. Anyone can use FireBug to change a html value and have it posted to the server.

In your serverside code, what business rule do you follow to determine if the user submitting the form is authorised to perform any given action?

You say in the html that they're not allowed to do a monthly subscription. On what business basis do you decide this? Once you're clear about that you can put it into code and check when the form is posted.

Comment: Thanks. So according to you, once the form is posted back I should check the business rules linked to the "enabling/disabling" of a specific option. Since in order to get the data for this check I need to make a database access which might influence performances, I gotta save such "rules"in the SessionState. Is it a good approach?

Comment: Hitting the database to do a check like this shouldn't be a huge performance loss. Like Ben said below, don't trust what comes back from your users. Do some testing to see if the 'Enabled' property is altered when you change the html using FireBug. It'll take you 2 minutes to verify Bens answer and decide on your own approach.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `.Enabled` property can't be changed with JavaScript, you're fine with what you have (test this for yourself to confirm). That said, there is a more thorough way of setting this up:

Use a separate model to populate the rdbSubscriptionType items collection (enabled, value and display text), then on the server side, compare against that model, not against the `asp:RadioButtonList` control itself.

Comment: thanks is sounds like a good solution (reminds the ViewModel approach). Just a small remark, in the answer by Jamie Dixon it is stated that anybody by using FireBug can change HTML values and post them to the server. That's what I was scared about when I decided to ask the question

Comment: Yes, Jamie is correct, you must not trust what comes from the user. In your case however, the .Enabled property we're referring to is a setting of the server, it isn't overwritten by the client on postback. ASP.Net muddies the client-server divide (by design), which can lead to confusion like this - the cleanest way of solving this is to use a separate model and prioritise that.